# Postgres sum of values one per unique id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to get a sum of the values from the column2, but I should calculate it only once per id. 
For example for the table below I need 5 + 10 + 7 and not 5 + 5 + 10 + 7

```
id column1 column2
1  value1  5
1  value1  5
2  value1  10
3  value1  7
```

The latter I get by the following query, but I don't know how to adapt it to get the first sum. Should I filter the table beforehand like selecting all the distinct rows?

```
SELECT column1, sum(column2) FROM table group by column1;
```

Comment: `sum(distinct column2)`

Comment: If you need sum for id, you should group by id.

Comment: But what happens if you have multiple distinct `column2` values for a given `id`?  Which one are you supposed to sum?  In your example it's easy, because they both have a value of `5`. But what if they were different?

Comment: @PawełDyl I sum by value1 (column1), but the id should stay unique

Comment: @sstan For the same id they will have the same column2

Comment: What is the purpose of column1, its value appears to be constant?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `sum(distinct clmn)` is not correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider cleaning up your data to remove the duplicate rows.  But the following query should get the results you want by first grouping by `id, column1` to remove the duplicates:

```
select column1, sum(column2)
  from (select id, column1, min(column2) as column2
          from tbl
         group by id, column1) t
 group by column1
```

Comment: what is the significance of min(column2) in subquery?? even without min() doesnt it do the same thing?

Comment: @krithikaGopalakrisnan I think its the requirement because it needs column2 to be aggregated

Answer (score 6):

Create custom aggregate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_func (
  double precision, pg_catalog.anyelement, double precision
)
RETURNS double precision AS
$body$
SELECT case when $3 is not null then COALESCE($1, 0) + $3 else $1 end
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE AGGREGATE dist_sum (
  pg_catalog."any", 
  double precision)
(
  SFUNC = sum_func,
  STYPE = float8
);
```

And then calc distinct sum like:

```
select dist_sum(distinct id, column2)
from table
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ae9a/1)

Comment: This allowed me to add the "sum B when A is distinct" logic into a very complex existing report query and avoid an yet another level of nesting. Thank you!